# How to install driver during my setup of msi files in windows

Tags: winforms, windows-installer, installation

I am working on a project where it needs to create a setup file (.msi) which install require third party driver during my setup of windows application.

Let me clear with example.
My application setup file - "mysetup.msi"
Other third party setup files - "installer.ini"

Is it possible that mysetup.msi automatically execute the setup for third party so my end user do not need to worry about the third party installation to use my software???

Comment: If you meant to write "installer.inf", then a [Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066(v=vs.85).aspx) that calls [InstallHinfSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376957%28VS.85%29.aspx) might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing drivers your best bet is to use DifXApp, the MSI version of the Driver Install Frameworks. Wix and InstallShield include these out of the box.